# EF Core Many to Many relation and HTTP calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I currently have 2 classes

```
public class Product 
{
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Height {get ; set; }
        public double Width {get ; set; }
        public double Depth {get ; set; }
        public ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Part
    {
            public int PartID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }
            public double Height {get ; set; }
            public double Width {get ; set; }
            public double Depth {get ; set; }
            public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

With a many to many relation since a product can be composed of multiple parts and a part can be used in many products.

I read that EF Core still doesn't handle this relation automatically so I will have this joining entity:

```
public class ProductPart
{
            public int ProductID { get; set; }
            public Product Product { get; set; }
            public int PartID { get; set; }
            public Part Part { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, when trying to answer the following calls to the api,

```
api/Product/{id}/Parts //Parts used in Product with {id}
api/Product/{id}/PartsIn //Products in which Part with {id} is used
```

do I have to write a ProductPartDTO and call that from the Product controller or how exactly do I handle these calls?

Comment: It all depends on what your clients require. For `api/product/{id}/parts`, you can simply return `List<Part>` and nullify the `Products` collection of each. It all depends if the `Part` class has all the info the client requires.

Answer (score 0):

I handle this in the DbContext OnModelCreating using a join table.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Parts)
                .WithMany(e => e.Products)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("ProductParts").MapLeftKey("PartID").MapRightKey("ProductID"));
}
```

One thing to note, you mention HTTP calls, if using JSON, the JSON serializer will have issues returning this data due to self referencing objects. You'll want to fill DTO (data transfer objects) that do not reference each other when you return your results.

Comment: With this I don't need to write the ProductPart class?
And to handle the calls just write each one in their respective Controller?

EDIT: I do have DTOs for each class (Product and Part).

Comment: Correct. You have three tables, Parts, Products, and ProductParts. Only create classes for Parts and Products with self referencing properties. EF can handle the rest. Just note, when sending the data over REST as JSON, you'll need a DTO that does not reference each other, XML is okay.

Comment: Thanks, I will approach it this way. I do have a DTO for each without the Parts and Products respectively.

Comment: 1) DTO means *Data Transfer Object* not *transformation*.  2) EF cannot handle [many to many](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration) 3) Sending it as JSON will work without a DTO by simply nullifying the self referencing property. Just an FYI ;)

Comment: Thanks for the correction @CodingYoshi, that was what I meant.

Comment: I'm confused, does that mean I still have to create another class, as per the link provided by @CodingYoshi?

Comment: @idetodospoca if you want EF to create the tables for you, yes you will need to create another class. I've your tables already exist and you just want to get data then you don't need to create it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi is correct. It depends on whether you are doing a code first vs. database first scenario.